# Why didn’t my <video autoplay> element start playing on the iPhone until I tapped it? Even with JavaScript?

Tags: iphone, html, video

On my iPhone, I tried the following HTML and JavaScript:

```
<video id="myvideo" src="" width="352" height="288" autoplay></video>

<script>
var vdo = document.getElementById('myvideo');
vdo.src = 'http://server-address:9902/208AC328657F5332-live-1.m3u8';
vdo.play();
</script>
```

But the video element didn't start playing until I tappped it. Why?

Thanks, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

The autoplay attribute is ignored on iPhone. It's just a decision they made in their implementation, just like they did with controls (they display no matter what.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to load video first...

```
<video id="myvideo" src="" width="352" height="288" autoplay></video>

<script>
var vdo = document.getElementById('myvideo');
vdo.src = 'http://server-address:9902/208AC328657F5332-live-1.m3u8';
vdo.load(); // video must be loaded
vdo.play(); // after success load it can be played
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you literally put that JavaScript into your HTML, straight after the video tag?

I’m not sure if it would work anyway, but you need to have the JavaScript in `<script>` tags for it to be interpreted as JavaScript:

```
<video id="myvideo" src="" width="352" height="288" autoplay></video>

<script>
var vdo = document.getElementById('myvideo');
vdo.src = 'http://server-address:9902/208AC328657F5332-live-1.m3u8';
vdo.play();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, but '<script>' tag in HTML is there, I am sorry, I forgot to write in the above. And I have change the vdo.src to a real streaming url.

Comment: @yanhsy: no problem, just thought I’d check.